# State not updating from useEffect hook - Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to update the state in my component using `useEffect`

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      let response = await getAccountCoverTypes();
      setData(response);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

I am setting my default value:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({
payload: { title: "", accountCoverTypes: [] },
```

And trying to map through the data

```
  const {
    payload: { title, accountCoverTypes },
  } = data;

{accountCoverTypes.map((button, index) => (
      ...
    ))}
```

When I try and use the data - I get the error, **Cannot read property title of undefined.** How can update the state from `useEffect`?

My service call:

```
const call = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await getItem(xxx);
        return response
}
```

json returned:

```
{
   "payload": {
      "title": "text here",
      "accountCoverTypes": [
         {
            "title": "sample text",
            "details": "sample text",
            "link": "test"
         },..
  
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with this code, actually I've rewrote it in a codesandbox and it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-williams-nts9y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: can you add more code to find the problem

Comment: I have added more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    let response = await getAccountCoverTypes();
    setData(response);
  }

  fetchData();
}, []);



{
  data &&
  data.accountCoverTypes &&
  data.accountCoverTypes.length &&
  data.accountCoverTypes.map((button, index) => (
      ...
))}
```

Before looping or iterating through the data variable, you should check the presence of data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when your function first time executed data value will be undefined, as you do not set any initial value for that state `const [data, setData] = useState()//initial value is not set;`
Your approach is absolutely correct in sense of updating data using setData function invoked from your useEffect hook. Once your async function executed - data will be updated and component will be rerendered

Answer (score -1):

React relies on the order in which Hooks are called.https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html
That means that after the useEffect runs, the useState reinitializes the data

So move the useState before the useEffect in your code

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      let response = await getAccountCoverTypes();
      setData(response);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```